# Antlr4 ParserATNSimulator Debugger generate no Output

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, antlr, antlr4

Is there a possibility to get the ParserATNSimulator Debuggingmessaging in python3 to work?

I tried to get to the core of ANTLR4 for python 3 and messed a bit with the ATN Simulation. There i wonder about the Class Attributes in ParserATNSimulator() for debugging.

```
class ParserATNSimulator(ATNSimulator):

    debug = False
    debug_list_atn_decisions = False
    dfa_debug = False
    retry_debug = False
```

Checking the code i see that this should print a lot of Information about the decision making in ANTLR4.

```
if self.debug or self.debug_list_atn_decisions:
print("predictATN decision " + str(dfa.decision) +
      " exec LA(1)==" + self.getLookaheadName(input) +
      ", outerContext=" + outerContext.toString(self.parser))
```

Unfortunately it Producing no output when i tried to set it True. Other
parts work as expected.
Is there a possibility to get this information?

```
  def main(argv):
    istream = FileStream(argv[1])
    lexer = ExLexer(istream)
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = ExParser(stream)
    parser._interp.debug = True
    parser._interp.debug_list_atn_decisions = True
    parser._interp.dfa_debug = True
    parser._interp.retry_debug = True
    parser.stat()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It works fine. `pip install -r requirements.txt`, then modified the cached files. Pip tells you where the sources for the runtime are.

Comment: @kaby76 i have no requirements.txt, but my antlr4-python3-runtime is working fine. But what do you mean by modified cached files? Should i manipulate the class in the source?

Comment: I have no idea how you are writing your program driver. Usually one uses pip to pull in packages needed. E.g., ` pip install antlr4-python3-runtime==4.10`. Pip tells you where to find the sources locally, e.g., "Requirement already satisfied: antlr4-python3-runtime==4.10 in c:\users\kenne\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (4.10)", which you can then go and modify ParserATNSimulator.py directly for debug. Otherwise, do a "find / -name ParserATNSimulator.py".

Comment: @kaby76 Thanks, this works just fine when I changed the sourcecode of the runtime! But why does my code doesnt change the behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure why. Seems like your code should work because __init__() is called, and you set the fields on _interp afterwards. I can only suggest see what it does by stepping through with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I get it with @kaby76's help to print output.
I edited the variables in the class in the path. `.../site-packages/antlr/antlr4-python3-runtime/atn/ParserATNSimulator.py`.